# Execute Gimp command to console application from Java

Tags: java, console, command, gimp

I am trying to execute a command line from a java program.

I have sucessfully managed to make this command line work when directly entered in a console on my MAC:
`/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp -i -b "(let* ( ( image (car (file-png-load 1 \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img.png\" \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img.png\") ) ) (drawable (car (gimp-image-active-drawable image) ) ) ) (plug-in-colortoalpha 1 image drawable '(0 0 0) ) (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img2.png\" \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img2.png\") ) " -b "(gimp-quit 0)"`

(I know, complicated, but it works)

The command successfully makes the black background of a picture transparent and saves the result.

So I have made the following program:

```
    try {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String command = "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp -i -b "
                + "\"(let* "
                + "("
                + "(image (car (file-png-load 1 \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img.png\" \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img.png\")))"
                + "(drawable (car (gimp-image-active-drawable image))) "
                + ")"
                + "(plug-in-colortoalpha 1 image drawable '(0 0 0))"
                + "(gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img2.png\" \"/Users/Maxime/Desktop/img2.png\")"
                + ")\" -b \"(gimp-quit 0)\"";

        String command2 = "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp -i -b \"(gimp-quit 0)\"";

        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);

        BufferedReader processOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        int lineCounter = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            String line = processOutput.readLine();
            if(line == null) break;
            System.out.println(++lineCounter + ": " + line);
        }

        processOutput.close();


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ColorToAlpha.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Unfortunately, the output stops after printing the following when I use command2:

```
1: gimp
2: /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS
3: /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/:/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I don't know what is happening, because even using command2 (simplyfied version of command) the program blocks.

If someone knows how to do so, it would be great.

EDIT: When I replace `String command` by `String[] command` and add quotes around, the program runs successfully, but nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see which line it's blocking on?

Comment: Yes, I have. It is blocking on the third iteration of my while loop, that is why it prints only three lines. The ouput I showed is the output from command2, which is only one line of command

Comment: It's possible that the `BufferedReader` doesn't return if it doesn't find a newline at the end of the output (i.e. the end of the stream is reached but we have characters in our buffer with no newline). Try reading the stream character-by-character using just `read` and printing that to the console instead (using `print` instead of `println`).

Comment: Even using `read()` instead of `readLine()` the program stops